# Does Android Process.killProcess(pid) kill just process or whole Application?

Tags: android

In Android I can use **Process.killProcess(pid)** to kill my process.

However If I have multiple main processes in the my Application defined in the Manifest using **android:process="com.some.name"** will it kill all of them or just the one for which the call was made?

Answer (score 1):

From [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#killProcess(int)) Process.killProcess(pid) does

> Kill the process with the given PID. Note that, though this API allows
>   us to request to kill any process based on its PID, the kernel will
>   still impose standard restrictions on which PIDs you are actually able
>   to kill. Typically this means only the process running the caller's
>   packages/application and any additional processes created by that app;
>   packages sharing a common UID will also be able to kill each other's
>   processes.

If you kill your main process others will live becoming an [Orphan process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphan_process)

Comment: So I think you are saying the answer is that it will kill only the android:process that it was called for and not all processes in the Application

Comment: It will kill the process with pid that you pass to this method. And I can only be the process itself or other processes created by it.

Answer (score 1):

This might help if you really need to kill all your app processes.

```
public static void killAppProcesses(Context context) {
    Log.i(TAG, "killAppProcesses; ");

    int myPid = Process.myPid();
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (activityManager != null) {
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> processInfos =
                activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
        if (processInfos != null) {
            String packageName = context.getPackageName();
            for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : processInfos) {
                if (processInfo.pid != myPid) { // Current process will be killed last
                    if (processInfo.pkgList != null) {
                        List<String> packageNames = Arrays.asList(processInfo.pkgList);
                        if (packageNames.contains(packageName)) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "killAppProcesses; killing process: " + processInfo.pid);
                            Process.killProcess(processInfo.pid);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Log.i(TAG, "killAppProcesses; killing my process: " + myPid);
    Process.killProcess(myPid);
}
```